# Python / pandas group by a column and join the text. Allow repeated grouping variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some text analysis and the sample data is as follows:

[image]

What I want is to join the `text` for a person until the next person appears on `name` column and conserve the order.

The output should look like:

```
name    text
Tom     hello, I am doing good how are you?
Pink    I am doing good. How is your project going? Any plans this weekend?
Tom     Hey, no plans this weekend. I am super busy Need to take my daugher to her gymnastics and swimming classes.
Pink    Alright. Have fun buddy See you later.
```

So far I have done this: Reproducible Example below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'Tom',
  1: 'tom ',
  2: 'Pink',
  3: 'Pink',
  4: 'Pink',
  5: 'Tom',
  6: 'Tom',
  7: 'Pink',
  8: 'Pink'},
 'text': {0: 'hello, I am doing good',
  1: 'how are you?',
  2: 'I am doing good. ',
  3: 'How is your project going?',
  4: 'Any plans this weekend?',
  5: 'Hey, no plans this weekend. I am super busy',
  6: 'Need to take my daugher to her gymnastics and swimming classes.',
  7: 'Alright. Have fun buddy',
  8: 'See you later. '}})
dat.groupby(['name'])['text'].apply(''.join)
```

The output I get is

```
name
Pink    I am doing good. How is your project going?Any...
Tom     hello, I am doing goodHey, no plans this weeke...
tom                                          how are you?
Name: text, dtype: object
```

This is not what i am looking for. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
grp = (dat['name'] != dat['name'].shift()).cumsum()
dat.groupby(grp)['text'].apply(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
name
1                               hello, I am doing good
2                                         how are you?
3    I am doing good.  How is your project going? A...
4    Hey, no plans this weekend. I am super busy Ne...
5              Alright. Have fun buddy See you later. 
Name: text, dtype: object
```

With name:

```
grp = (dat['name'] != dat['name'].shift()).cumsum().rename('order')
dat.groupby(['name', grp])['text'].apply(' '.join).sort_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
name  order
Tom   1                                   hello, I am doing good
tom   2                                             how are you?
Pink  3        I am doing good.  How is your project going? A...
Tom   4        Hey, no plans this weekend. I am super busy Ne...
Pink  5                  Alright. Have fun buddy See you later. 
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I want. Really appreciate your solution.

Comment: I think the first two lines should be joined. You have 5 rows. There should be four rows. Tom is repeated. Is it because of the case of tom in second line ?

Comment: Upper and lowcase Tom vs tom?

Comment: Thanks. That was it

Comment: Is there any way to make this code faster? I have more than 20 millions rows and this code is taking quite a time to run. If you could point me to ways to make it faster, I would appreciate it.